# Sort by shares in YouTube Analytics API v2

Tags: youtube-api, google-api-nodejs-client, youtube-analytics-api

I am using Youtube Analytics API to get the video that has most of the shares among all. Here is the query I am using:

```
youtube.reports.query({
        auth: oAuth,
        endDate: todayDateString,
        startDate: startDateString,
        ids: 'channel==MINE',
        metrics: 'shares',
        dimensions: 'video',
        sort: '-shares',
        maxResults: 1
    }
```

but it gives me an error that "Query not supported"